# Safe-ing wall-mounted cabinets for storage and transport

Tags: cabinets

I am removing cabinets mounted on my garage to put in storage and then move to an undeveloped property.  The cabinets are multi-door, wall mounted 1/2 and in. fiberboard.  All of them are built with one 4" wide horizontal fiberboard wall-mounting member across the inside top.  To add to the stress of the task, I want to move them (as opposed to land-filling them) because they were built by my late father.

I had to take some of them off the wall to make room for grid-tied batteries in the garage and have already discovered I need to immediately address the racking issue.  I am without help, so it is going to be furniture dollies and hand-trucks and their inherent "off-bore" vectors of force.

And that brings me to my question: what are the minimum things I can do to address the racking, preferably something hidden inside the carcass, like corner braces, if permanent; or, something temporary, but effective, such as strap-type clamps or a diagonal strip of wood(?).

I will happily accept any and all suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure they are made with fibreboard?  My understanding of fibreboard is a board more for insulation/sound reduction than structural.  Maybe you mean MDF or OSB?

Comment: If you place them on the hand truck with the back against the truck's upright, there should be minimal racking.

Answer (score 4):

I assume from the fact that you have a racking issue that they lack a back other than the mounting strip.

I'd attach a 1/8" plywood (whatever flavor you can get at most reasonable cost - luan, floor underlayment birch, etc..) back to them, which functions as a whole lot of X braces when it's fastened to the case all around. Or if plywood pricing is absurd but hardboard (Masonite®) isn't, that will work, too.

Answer (score 0):

I understand. Being they were made by your father, save them at all cost.

would add a simple "L" bracket at least 2 inch at all 4 inside corners. Leaving them there when the cabinets are hung at the new location.

Good Luck